# Setting the language worker retry start count?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VSCode I have the debugger automatically connecting to a node process, the debugger usually works to reattach itself on a typescript transpile but on occasion fails to attach with the error:

> Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:node.
>   Shutting down Functions Host

Is it possible to set the retry count and/or put the retries on a delay timer?